# How can I pass a function to click handler in the correct context?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object, onclick

I have to get an argument value from the function inside the `onlick` property of a button, but the function (`this.getListItemId(itemId)`) which makes use of this argument is not inside of the context from where the button is. The button is inside a child function 
 (`this.renderVideoListTemplate()`) which is inside a parent function (`getVideoListItems()`). The function i want call on the onclick event (`this.getListItemId()`) it is outside from where the function of the button (`this.renderVideoListTemplate()`) is, so it says the function (`this.getListItemId(itemId)`) does not exists.

```
var getVideoListItems = function() {
    var self = this;

    this.renderVideoListTemplate = function(result) {      

        for(let i=0; i < result.length; i++){  
    ====>>> var listItems ="<div class='Button fecharVideo' onclick='"+self.getListItemId(result[i].ID)+"'>"+ 
                                "<span class='Button'>Excluir Vídeo</span>"+
                            "</div>";

            $("#video-list-container").append(listItems);
        };
    };

    this.deleteListItem = function(webUrl, listName, itemId, success, failure) {
        self.getDataByItemId(webUrl,listName,itemId,function(item){
            $.ajax({
                url: item.__metadata.uri,
                type: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-Http-Method": "DELETE",
                    "If-Match": item.__metadata.etag
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    success();
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    failure(data.responseJSON.error);
                }
            });
        },
       function (error) {
           failure(error);
       });
    };

    this.getListItemId = function(itemId){
        self.deleteListItem(webUrl, listName, itemId)
    };

    return this.init();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign a function reference within the string value of an `onclick` attribute.

You could avoid the issue and improve the logic by instead using a delegated event handler. You can keep the `result[i].ID` in a `data` attribute on the `div` you create which can be read when the click event happens. Try this:

```js
// in your object:
this.renderVideoListTemplate = function(result) {
  var divs = result.map(function() {
    return `<div class="Button fecharVideo" data-id="${this.ID}"><span class="Button">Excluir Vídeo</span></div>`
  });
  $("#video-list-container").append(divs);
};

// somewhere else in your codebase:
$('#video-list-container').on('click', '.fecharVideo', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  yourObjectReferece.getListItemId($(this).data('id'));
})
```

Also note the use of `map()` to build an array of strings to append to the `#video-list-container` element once, instead of within every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

First of all when witing:
`<a href'#' onclick='this.getListItemId(itemId)'>...`
this. will refer to the Object(HTMLElement)  a who has the function.

Second:
Best way to  use listener is to use the .addEventListener FUNCTION such:
`document.querySelector('#id_of_element').addEventListener('click', function(e){
//-- do something with e arg is the event
})`

Using element.addEventListener(... separate code from the HTML , way clearer and easy to manipulate and use.
By the way use named function allow you to removeEventListener that will erase behaviour and lighten code way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using jQuery here, instead of using simple string you can create a jQuery element and add a listener with `$().on()`

So, this `for loop`:

```
        for(let i=0; i < result.length; i++){  
    ====>>> var listItems ="<div class='Button fecharVideo' onclick='"+self.getListItemId(result[i].ID)+"'>"+ 
                                "<span class='Button'>Excluir Vídeo</span>"+
                            "</div>";

            $("#video-list-container").append(listItems);
        };
```

can be transformed in the following one:

```
        for(let i=0; i < result.length; i++){  
            var listItems = $("<div class='Button fecharVideo'><span class='Button'>Excluir Vídeo</span></div>");
            listItems.on('click', function (){
                self.getListItemId(result[i].ID);
            });

            $("#video-list-container").append(listItems);
        };
```

Comment: The `on()` method isn't really needed here. `click()` would do fine.

Comment: @isherwood, it is a matter of preference here, .click method is a shortcut for .on( "click", handler ), you can read the docs https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Yep. I use `on()` when I need event delegation or when I need to handle multiple event types. Otherwise, shorthand methods such as `click()`, `blur()`, etc. seem cleaner.